# Change date format of the DatePickerDialog Calendar in Android

Tags: android

I'm using DatePickerDialog in my code. And I want to know, How to change date format of the DatePickerDialog Calendar in format dd mm yyyy.

My code is :-

```
public static class DatePickerDialogTheme5 extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");
            Date d=new Date();
            sdf.format(d);
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(d);

            calendar.set(calendar.YEAR,d.getYear());
            calendar.set(calendar.MONTH,d.getMonth());
            calendar.set(calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,d.getDay());

            int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog datepickerdialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                    //AlertDialog.THEME_TRADITIONAL,this,day,month,year);
            AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK,this,year,month,day);

            return datepickerdialog;
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day){    
            TextView textview = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView1);    
            textview.setText(day + ":" + (month+1) + ":" + year);    
        }
    }
```

[I Want to show Date Picker Dialog like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EU89.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what you would like to achieve, but you could use a `Calendar` instance with `SimpleDateFormat` to format your `Date` according to your needs.

For example:

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(year, month, day);

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yyyy");

    String dateString = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

    TextView textview = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textview.setText(dateString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Here i disabled previous dates also     

 inside onclick listener
    edit_event_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    DatePickerFragment dFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                    dFragment.show(DashBoardActivity.this.getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");

                }
            });   


     @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
        public class DatePickerFragment extends android.app.DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
            int year, month, day;


            @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
                dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
                return dpd;
            }

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int syear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
                view.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);//disable dates

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTimeInMillis(0); ////disable dates
                cal.set(syear, selectedmonth, selectedday, 0, 0, 0);
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                String dateString = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
//in loolipop disable dates also we can select so for that restriction below condition
                if (syear == year && (selectedmonth + 1) == month + 1) {
                    if (selectedday < day) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "invalid date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                edit_event_date.setText(dateString);


            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        edt_date_of_birth.setText(null);
        edt_date_of_birth.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);   

        int day = dayOfMonth;
        int yy = year;
        int month = ++monthOfYear;
        String str_day = day < 10 ? "0" + day : "" + day;
        String str_month = month < 10 ? "0" + month : "" + month;
        String date_select = String.valueOf(yy) + "-" + str_month + "-" + str_day;

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date1 = null;
        try {
            date1 = format.parse(date_select);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String date = format.format(date1);
        if(date.endsWith("01") && !date.endsWith("11"))
            format = new SimpleDateFormat("d'st' MMM, yyyy");
        else if(date.endsWith("02") && !date.endsWith("12"))
            format = new SimpleDateFormat("d'nd' MMM, yyyy");
        else if(date.endsWith("03") && !date.endsWith("13"))
            format = new SimpleDateFormat("d'rd' MMM, yyyy");
        else
            format = new SimpleDateFormat("d'th' MMM, yyyy");
        String yourDate = format.format(date1);
        edt_date_of_birth.setText(yourDate);
    }
```