# SQlite database not ordering by date

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have this method which is designed to list a series of transactions in date order when passed to an array only it appears in no order at all, don't know where i'm going wrong. I don't get any errors but doesn't actually work.

```
    public List<Record> getAllAccountRecords() {
        ArrayList<Record> all_Records = new ArrayList<Record>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_HISTORY +" ORDER BY 'COL_DATE' DESC";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Record record = new Record();
                record.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(COL_ID)));
                record.setAccountType(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_ACCOUNT_TYPE)));
                record.setDescription(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_DESCRIPTION)));
                record.setExpenseSource(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_EXPENSES_SOURCE)));
                record.setExpenseAmount(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_EXPENSES_AMOUNT)));
                record.setIncomeSource(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_INCOME_SOURCE)));
                record.setIncomeAmount(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_INCOME_AMOUNT)));
                record.setDate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_DATE)));

                all_Records.add(record);

            } while (c.moveToNext());
            c.close();
        }

        return all_Records;
```

**Call in main activity**
  Maybe its the writing to the array takes it back out of order, but how do I then order the array.

```
final List<Record> RecordsArray = mDatabase.getAllAccountRecords();

    if (RecordsArray.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < RecordsArray.size(); i++) {
            Record record = RecordsArray.get(i);
            if (record.getExpenseAmount() != null) {
                accountRecords.add('-' + "  £   " + record.getExpenseAmount() + "  " + `record.getExpenseSource()`
                        + "  " + record.getDate() + "  " + record.getRecordDescription());
            }
            if (record.getIncomeAmount() != null) {
                accountRecords.add('+' + "  £   " + record.getIncomeAmount() + "  " + `record.getIncomeSource()`
                        + "  " + record.getDate() + "  " + record.getRecordDescription());
            }

        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                R.layout.simple_list_item_1, accountRecords);

        historyList.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        historyList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {

                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                String text = "Description:
"
                        + RecordsArray.get(position).getRecordDescription();
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
    } else {


        mDatabase.closeDB();
    }

}
```

**Method to set date**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar cldr = Calendar.getInstance();
            int day = cldr.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int month = cldr.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int year = cldr.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            // date picker dialog
            picker = new DatePickerDialog(AddIncomeActivity.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            eText.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                            month_select = monthOfYear;
                        }
                    }, year, month, day);

            picker.show();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

`COL_DATE` is a variable that contains the name of the column but you use it as a string literal.
Change to:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_HISTORY +" ORDER BY " + COL_DATE + " DESC";
```

Comment: Hi, I've changed the query based on your advice and yet it still isn't in order.

Comment: dd/mm/yy inputted from a datepicker using Calendar

Comment: This is not a comparable format so the order you get is alphabetical. You should use only yyyy-mm-dd in SQLite tables.

Comment: In your app you can use any format you want but when you save the date to the database you must change it to yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: Sorry how do I change it to do that?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39046227/10498828 on how to change the format of a date (change dd:MM:yyyy to `yyyy-MM-dd`)

Comment: Thanks I looked at that and it doesn't make sense. Really all I need to do is save the date as a date format in the beginning before changing it to dd/mm/yyyy format but I can't work out how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
"SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_HISTORY +" ORDER BY 'COL_DATE' DESC"
```

The name of the column is surrounded with single quotes: this turns it to a *literal string*. So all rows get the same, literal value `'COL_DATE'` as ordering criteria, which makes the sort order undefined.

Just remove the single quotes and use the value of the variable, so SQLite recognizes that it is a column name:

```
"SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_HISTORY +" ORDER BY " + COL_DATE + " DESC"
```